# Xamarin Forms State Container View not Respecting Layout Options

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a basic State Management system found here: (code below)

https://github.com/xDelivered-Patrick/Xamarin.Forms.Essentials/blob/master/Essentials/Controls/State/StateContainer.cs

When implementing, my XAML View looks like the below.

The problem is the `StackLayout` `CenterAndExpand` is not working. All the views when rendered are simply scrunched at the top.

If I pull the particular section out of the `StateContainer` and eliminate its usage, it renders correctly. Is this an issue with the way the `View` is being rendered inside the Content of the `StateContainer`?

**EDIT: Here is a minimal example: https://github.com/aherrick/StateManagementDemo**

XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout x:Name="layoutWrap" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <controls:StateContainer State="{Binding State}">
            <controls:StateCondition Is="Loading">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                    <ActivityIndicator  x:Name="loadingIndicator"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                                    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </controls:StateCondition>

            <controls:StateCondition Is="Loaded">
                <!-- actual content here -->
            </controls:StateCondition>
            <controls:StateCondition Is="Error">

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                    <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Oops! There was a problem."  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Button Text="Tap to Retry" Command="{Binding LoadVenuesCommand}" CommandParameter="true"   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" Padding="15"  BackgroundColor="#26265E" />
                </StackLayout>
            </controls:StateCondition>
        </controls:StateContainer>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

C#

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class StateCondition : View
{
    public object Is { get; set; }
    public object IsNot { get; set; }
    public View Content { get; set; }
}

[ContentProperty("Conditions")]
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class StateContainer : ContentView
{
    public List<StateCondition> Conditions { get; set; } = new List<StateCondition>();

    // https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102024/change-bindableproperty-create-to-bindableproperty-create
    //public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(State), typeof(object), typeof(StateContainer), propertyChanged: StateChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = BindableProperty.Create<StateContainer, object>(x => x.State, null, propertyChanged: StateChanged);

    public static void Init()
    {
    }

    private static void StateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var parent = bindable as StateContainer;
        parent?.ChooseStateProperty(newValue);
    }

    public object State
    {
        get { return GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ChooseStateProperty(object newValue)
    {
        foreach (StateCondition stateCondition in Conditions)
        {
            if (stateCondition.Is != null)
            {
                if (stateCondition.Is.ToString().Equals(newValue.ToString()))
                {
                    Content = stateCondition.Content;
                }
            }
            else if (stateCondition.IsNot != null)
            {
                if (!stateCondition.IsNot.ToString().Equals(newValue.ToString()))
                {
                    Content = stateCondition.Content;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No thoughts on this? I've included a minimal example of the issue above in my GitHub

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: I ran a quick test on an android device. It seems to work as i described it bellow. Try it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple but not obvious. Add `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` to the `<local:StateContainer>` object as well. All Xamarin Forms `LayoutOptions` ending with ...AndExpand can olny expand if their containing parent allows it. That is why it worked when you removed the element from the `<local:StateContainer>` and put it directly in the `StackLayout` that allready had `FillAndExpand` declared thereby "allowing expansion".

Comment: No Problem, happy to help!